# How do I boot to safe mode in Mac OSX 10.9.3?

Tags: macos, safe-mode, firmware-password

I followed the instructions [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH14204?viewlocale=en_US) but it did not seem to work. How do I boot to safe mode? I am on Mavericks 10.9.3.

Comment: Are you saying the Firmware password request did not come up?

Comment: No it did not. It just booted up normally i.e. as if I had not been holding down the Shift key. Is your experience different @Buscar웃?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that I had to turn off my firmware password to be able to do this. [Here](http://osxdaily.com/2014/01/06/set-firmware-password-mac/) are some steps to resetting the firmware password. Note that you will need to know your firmware password to be able to reset it!

Comment: Please mark this answer as correct if you feel this question has been answered

Comment: I certainly will! As soon as the system allows me (I have wait another day at the time of writing as it's an answer from myself).